# How to know total ROM space on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Some Windows Phone Model has different ROM version, for example, HTC 8x has two versions, 8g and 16g. How can I know my device is which one through API?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/24/windows-phone-7-how-to-get-phone-and-application-memory-information.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot get it. You could create a mapping from the device ID to the actual size, but that wouldn't work for the future devices.

Comment: It returns the physical RAM size of the device in bytes, not for ROM.